# Linked Items in Sandcastle project

Tags: sandcastle, xml-documentation

The Sandcastle documentation for [Folder and File Items](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/0a9d6da4-cff6-4664-8b64-b7df04c8a37d.htm) notes at the end that:

> The project supports linked items as well (adding them is not supported from the standalone GUI). Linked items will have a **Remove** option rather than a **Delete** option. This removes them from the project but leaves them on disk in their original location since they may belong to another project.

How does one add such linked items (*outside* the GUI, since it is stated that they can't be added via the standalone GUI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not baffled alone. It's on the issue list of SHFB and the problem is described by Eric Woodruff at: [Clarify support for 'Linked Items'](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/issues/319)

The standalone GUI supports them for use but can't add them. They can be added in Visual Studio in the usual manner. Select the option to add an existing item and in the file selection dialog box, rather than clicking the Add button, click the drop down arrow on it and select the Add as Link option.

Maybe this is a workaround for you.

Comment: Thanks. The part about how to manually add linked items directly into the `shfbproj` file is good to know for those using the standalone GUI without VS.